# How to close window when clicking outside window in ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I've been working on this task for a while now and can't get it work. Basically I have this window that I'm able to toggle when clicking on **"toggle button"**, but I'm trying to close window when user clicks anywhere outside the window and I'm not having any luck with it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I found a solution but it's uses ExtJS 6, and I'm using version 4.1. Thanks a lot in a advance!

**Here's my code:**

```
button.on('click', function() {
if (myWindow.isVisible()) {
    myWindow.hide();

  } else {
    myWindow.show();
    myWindow.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), "tr-tr", [-10, 10]);
  }
 }, this);

}
```

Here's [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/9satfr40/17/)

Now, I found this code that works but it uses Extjs 6.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
float: true,
width: 300,
height: 200,
listeners: {
    focusleave: function (cmp) {
        cmp.close();
    }
},
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}).show();
```

This is the [**LINK**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ju9) to this version using Extjs 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

```js
var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    modal: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    listeners: {
    el: {
        blur: function () {
           this.hide();
           Ext.getCmp(this.id).setVisible(false);
           }
        }
    }
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Included `Ext.getCmp(this.id).setVisible(false);` in the blur event.

**UPDATE**

Use `mousedown` event instead of click because it envoke before blur.

```js
 button.mon(button.getEl(), { 

    'mousedown': function() {

      if (myWindow.isVisible()) {
        myWindow.hide();

      } else {
        myWindow.show();
        myWindow.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), "tr-tr", [-10, 10]);
      }

    }

  });
```

If you want to toggle with enterkey press on button. Then include `keydown` event also.

```js
button.getEl().on({
  scope: this,
  keydown: function(e, obj) {
   if(e.keyCode===13) {
      if (myWindow.isVisible()) {
        myWindow.hide();

      } else {
        myWindow.show();
        myWindow.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), "tr-tr", [-10, 10]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you use keydown event don't forgot to add `enableKeyEvents` config to true in button definition.

```
  var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Toggle Window',
    enableKeyEvents:true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nwhm24x/) is the working fiddle.

Comment: your solution kind of works, but when I want to open the window again I have to double click. Any ideas how to solve that? thanks

Comment: your solution still requires the double click. Not working properly

Comment: the toggling is broken with your solution

Comment: your jsfiddlle doesn't work. The toggling functionality on the button is broken

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer with detailed explanation. Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5nwhm24x/

Answer (score 0):

As Gokul's answer you can add a `blur` event on `el` and hide the window. Whereas while toggling visible property is not modified so you have to make it as false to avoid double click.

```
el: {
   blur: function () {
       myWindow.hide();
       myWindow.setVisible(false);
   }          
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6jexf1a/) is the working fiddle

Comment: your solution still requires the double click. Not working properly

Comment: the toggling is broken with your solution